# Sharing Session between ServiceStack in an MVC app and separate Web services project

Tags: servicestack

I have an MVC Powerpack Web app that has minimal servicestack configuration that also talks to a separate ServiceStack web project that acts as the API. So in other words, all of my services, auth, and registration are coming from the services project, not the MVC project.  In the MVC project I have my controllers inheriting from ServiceStackController and am using a CustomUserSession as shown in the SocialBootstrapApi demo.

I am wondering what the best approach is to allow me to share session information between the two projects.  I would like to be able to decorate my Controllers with the [Authenticate] attribute and use the ServiceStack authentication in the MVC app as well.

I have looked at various examples, also as mentioned the SocialBootstrapApi app - most of the examples show ServiceStack configured in 1 project.  How can this be implemented with separate projects so that I can share session info between the 2 and get access to the CustomUserSession while at the same time being able to use the [Authenticate] tags to lock down my Controllers?

Answer (score 1):

If your two applications are on the same domain they should be able to read the same auth cookies. If they are on two separate domains then you have to implement some kind of Single Sign-On process / handshake.

I am not sure what kind of cookie ServiceStack drops, but if your MVC application has a reference to ServiceStack auth libraries then you should be able to decode the cookie that ServiceStack spits out and set the User Principal on your MVC application.

```
 HttpContext.User = DecodeServiceStackAuthCookie(HttpContext.Current);

 IPrincipal DecodeServiceStackAuthCookie(HttpContext context) { /* your code */ }
```

Hope that gets you going on the right path.